# Sharepoint and Exchange Powershell Remoting with Variables

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, exchange-server, remoting

I am trying to run a script that:

Pulls a user list from SharePoint 2013
Defines variables based on "for each" (for the `new-mailbox` cmdlet)
Runs the `New-mailbox` cmdlet 
writes back the processed $date in the SP list.

I have read that I am not suppose to install SharePoint snap-ins on an Exchange Server and vice-versa.

How do I go about doing this? Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is no SharePoint snap-in separate install. The SharePoint cmdlets are installed only if you install SharePoint software.

You can, however, use the implicit remoting method to access both Exchange and SharePoint cmdlets on the same system.

Follow the instructions here: http://www.ravichaganti.com/blog/?p=1151

Comment: I got most of it to work with the import - pssession command. Part of the script checks for an existing username via the dsquery command. This is not passed through the remote session. Do I have to load RSAT on the Sharepoint server to be able to dsquery users? I was also wondering if the active directory snapin would be the way to go to try to get some values back from existing users but I don't want to have to rewrite the script with different commands id i dont' have to.

Comment: Or I guess I could try it backwards importing the sharepoint session and commands into exchange management console to get the dsquery since it seems to work from there.

Comment: This is the same result as dsquery. Looking for a Null value if it doesn't exist.          get-user -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$loginID1'"